# How can I access an array of multi-level objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, javascript-objects

By looking at the "[Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0hpS.png)" image, how can I access all levels of this array?

I tried doing a foreach but this only allows me to access to the first object, I can't acces the second object filled with strings.

```
    for (var key in result)
  {
     if (result.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
          console.log(key, result[key]);

              for(var item in result[key])
                {
                  console.log(item);
                 }
          }
}
```

I also tried:

```
result[key[item]]
```

But it appears to be undifined.

I know it's easy to access all elements by the name, but the names change constantly, so the solution should be dynamic.

I added the Demo on the comments to see behavior.

Comment: DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/jaelsvd/tkgn1bgt/3/

Comment: please add the relavant data to the question.

Comment: Hi Jael, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited the question, hope it's more clear, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys(obj)` returns an array of the keys in `obj`.

```js
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  m: 3,
  x: 4,
  y: 5,
  z: 6
}

//get all the keys in an array:
var keys = Object.keys(obj)
console.log("keys: " + keys);

//iterate through the object by its keys:
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  console.log("key " + keys[i] + " has value " + obj[keys[i]]);
}
```

## Update based on your comment

I think you're asking to apply this solution to an arbitrary-depth object. My solution would be to wrap the previous trick in a function and call it recursively if there are nested objects:

```js
var obj = {
  a: {foo:"bar",foof:"barf"},
  b: 2,
  m: 3,
  x: {baz:{really:{more:{objects: "yeah, there could be a lot"}}}},
  y: 5,
  z: 6
}

function getKeysDeep(obj,prefix){
  //get all the keys in an array:
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
  //console.log(prefix + "keys: " + keys);

  //iterate through the object by its keys:
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    if (obj[keys[i]] !== null && typeof obj[keys[i]] === 'object') {
      console.log("key " + keys[i] + "'s value is an object");
      getKeysDeep(obj[keys[i]],prefix + keys[i] + ": ");
    } else {
      console.log(prefix + "key " + keys[i] + " has value " + obj[keys[i]]);
    }
  }
}

getKeysDeep(obj,"")
```

Comment: This allows me to access to the first object contect, but if I had a: { 1: test} it wouldn't allow me to acces to "test"

Answer (score 0):

This loop worked too!

```
Object.keys(result).forEach(function (key) {
      console.log(result[key]);
      var test = result[key];
      Object.keys(test).forEach(function (key) {
         console.log(test[key]);
         var testTwo = test[key];
          Object.keys(testTwo).forEach(function (key) {
            console.log(testTwo[key]);
            var testThree = testTwo[key];
          });
       });
    });
```

But @nvioli answer is more accurate.